# Severe depression/anxiety can't be treated with CBT

Tags: cognitive-psychology, depression, anxiety

Is there any evidence that supports the idea that a severe depression/anxiety can't be treated with CBT?

Since, it's in severe state, and one has to use anti-depressants to lower the level, and then obviously CBT can help reduce a moderate to low level depression. Is a severe depression/anxiety too strong to be healed by CBT, and it makes the usage of anti-depressants necessary?

Comment: Do you mean with CBT cognitive behavioral therapy? Could you explain the acronym at least once in your post?

Comment: Related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/1977/7604

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is the consensus view among psychiatrists and clinical psychologists (*e.g.*, [Parker *et al*., 2012](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23240706)). A commonly referenced authoritative guideline for treatment of major depressive disorder is the [NICE guide](https://www.nice.org.uk/guidance/cg90/chapter/1-Guidance).

**Reference**
[Parker *et al*., *Acta Psychiatr Scand* (2013); **128**(4): 271-81](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23240706)

Comment: A study done with only 18 people over only 3 months, to me, doesn't seem to be even close to convincing.

Comment: @WilliamOliver - While I understand that the number of subjects might be a little low for your liking, 3 months is definitely long enough for an initial study, seeing as CBT (Cognitive Based Therapy) is inherently designed for a maximum of 6-12 sessions.

Comment: @ChrisRogers that is a fair point.